# Proving that a sequence is Cauchy (given the relationship between any two consecutive terms)

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

I am given a sequence, $s_{n}$, and told that, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $|s_{n+1}-s_{n}|<\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. I am asked to prove that $s_n$ is Cauchy. Is the following headed in the right direction?

Suppose WLOG that $m=n+k, k\in \mathbb{N}$. So $|s_{m+k}-s_{n}|\leq|s_{n+k}-s_{n+k-1}|+\cdot \cdot \cdot |s_{n+1}-s_{n}|$ (by the triangle inequality) $< \frac{1}{2^{n+k-1}}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +\frac{1}{2^{n}}<\frac{k}{2^{n}}$ (k lots of $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$, the largest term in the sum on the left hand side) < $\frac{k}{n}$. So, choose $N=\frac{k}{\epsilon}$, so that $m>n>N \implies|s_{m+k}-s_{n}|<\epsilon.$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good, but your $N$ isn't allowed to depend on $k$, because then our $N$ will be depend on $m,n$ and that is bad.

Just think of the geometric series. For $m>n\geq N$ we have
$$
|s_m-s_n|\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} |s_{k+1}-s_k|\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \frac{1}{2^k}\leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\leq \frac{1}{2^{N-1}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. But why, exactly, is N not allowed to depend on m and n?

Comment: If we fix $\varepsilon>0$, then you should be able to calculate $N$. But with your choice it is not possible, because your $N$ depends on the difference between $m$ and $n$. If the difference $m-n$ is very big but $n$ is small, your $N$ could be larger than $n$. Your choice is $N:=\frac{|m-n|}{\varepsilon}$, right? Then $n<N$ can happen.